# how to wait till locaiton manager delegate called in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

i have a general function genParam() as soon as i called this method , i want to return the current userGPS location along with other parameters.but in my case genParam() returning immediately before calling the delegate method didUpdateLocations.Is there any way to wait till delegate method gets called before returning genParam().

```
class CommonApiParamGenerator: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var userGPSLoc:String = ""

func genParam(locationName:String)->NSMutableDictionary{

    self.getUserLocation()
    let guid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let userName = SingleTon.sharedInstance.getUserName()
    let gpsLoc = self.userGPSLoc
   let commonParam = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [guid,userName,gpsLoc], forKeys: ["guid","userName","gpsLoc"])
    return commonParam

}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    self.userGPSLoc = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    print("receivedGPS \(self.userGPSLoc)")
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}


 func getUserLocation()
{
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly accroding to single responsibility principle I propose you to move you code with getting location in separate class:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    private var completion: ((CLLocation) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func getLocation(completion: (CLLocation) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.completion?(userLocation)
    }
}
```

Then refactor you class:

```
class CommonApiParamGenerator: NSObject {
    var userGPSLoc:String = ""
    var locationManager = LocationManager()

    func genParam(locationName:String, completion: (NSMutableDictionary) -> Void) {
        let guid = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let userName = SingleTon.sharedInstance.getUserName()

        locationManager.getLocation { location in
            let userGPSLoc = "\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
            completion(NSMutableDictionary(objects: [guid,userName,userGPSLoc], forKeys: ["guid","userName","gpsLoc"]))
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let generator = CommonApiParamGenerator()
generator.genParam(locationName) { params in
    ...
}
```

Main idea is using callbacks for asynchronous operations.

If you don't like callbacks, or there are a lot of nested callbacks (callback hell) you can you PromiseKit: http://promisekit.org/.
Good luck!

Comment: not working. returning immediately before didUpdateLocations gets called..

Comment: @adarshaU, a little bit later I will create app and will check everything, and will give you link to repo